# How to create grid system in Drupal

Tags: drupal-7

https://i.stack.imgur.com/kW2RT.png

I want to create a grid system like the one in picture in drupal 7. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

I first tried using Zen, but I could not figure out how to use SASS  to make this grid system.

Then, I checked out the panels module, but that also wont help; it only makes more columns, but I want to make more rows.

I am very comfortable with CSS and php so if you have suggestions regarding modifying a certain CSS or php file, its more than enough. Just let me know which file to modify, and what to look for...

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried something like [Omega](http://drupal.org/project/omega)? If you know CSS then with the regions it provides you should be able to achieve that structure.

Answer (score 0):

[Omega](http://drupal.org/project/omega) is definitely perfect for this grid use case.  Try it out!

If you'd like to stick with Zen though, it is worth noting that using SASS is not required to use Zen - [from the Zen project page](http://drupal.org/project/zen):

> *If you're not ready for Sass yet, Zen still includes a full set of well-documented CSS files. Sass integration adds zero overhead, so if you simply ignore all of Zen's Sass, your site performance isn’t penalized. No worries!*